# How do add image with paperclip after signup of user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

I am trying to add an option where user can edit the profile pic which was uploaded by `paperclip` gem. But all the examples I got from internet are explaining how to add image while registering user, not once registered. How do I do it? I am using devise for user registration.

```
  def create
    @user = User.where(id: current_user.id)
    ??
    ??
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
  end
```

What should be added in the controller action `create` so that we can save image to `User` model?

Edit:

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :thumb => "59x59#" },, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.jpg"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Also while user registration the default image is displayed, there is no option for choosing image while user registration.

Comment: Can you please provide the code from the User model? It will add more context for the person that answers the question.

Comment: @IleEftimov: Updated

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be as simple as:

```
 def create
  @user = User.where(id: current_user.id)
  @user.avatar = params[:user][:avatar]
  @user.save
 end
```

This should assign the file that you are sending to the User, and save the user, including the file. The file will be stored in your `public` directory (or, in the path that you configured).

Then, in your views, you should be able to call the avatar as:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I get error "NoMethodError in UserProfileController#create
undefined method `avatar=' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fea96667410>"

Comment: Can you check your schema for the presence of the avatar column on your users table?

Comment: t.string   "avatar_file_name",       limit: 255
    t.string   "avatar_content_type",    limit: 255
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size",       limit: 4
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"

Comment: In your User model, do you have "has_attached_file :avatar" ?